# Runtime Erro : Play 2.5

Tags: java, playframework

I have downloaded Play 2.5 and am creating a sample application. I am creating simple form. Below is the code. I am getting runtime error while using `private static final Form<Product> productForm = Form.form(Product.class);` :

```
public class Products extends Controller {

    private static final Form<Product> productForm = Form.form(Product.class);


    public Result list(){
        List<Product> products = Product.findAll();
        return ok(list.render(products));
    }


    public  Result newProduct(){
        //return ok(details.render(productForm));
        return TODO;
    }

    public Result details(String ean){
        return TODO;
    }

    public Result save(){
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> Internal server error, for (GET) [/] -> play.api.UnexpectedE‌​xception: Unexpected exception[ExceptionI‌​nInitializerError: null] at play.core.server.Dev‌​ServerStart$$anonfun$‌​mainDev$1$$anon$1$$an‌​onfun$get$1$$anonfun$‌​apply$1$$anonfun$1.ap‌​ply(DevServerStart.sc‌​ala:174)

Comment: I am getting following error :

Comment: ! @714lj134f - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ExceptionInInitializerError: null]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:174)

Comment: added error message displayed in the comment